# android jaxws-api dependency causing conflict

Tags: android, xml, gradle

I used wsimport to generate classes from wsdl. now I'm resolving missing dependencies and some of them belongs to the javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:

`import javax.xml.ws.Service;
 import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException;
 import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;`
gradle build fails when I add the dependency:

**Error:Conflict with dependency 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (1.2-b03) and test app (1.2) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.**

Why does that dependency cause this strange error? I tried changing the version and removing some other dependencies from the build.gradle but nothing. here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.prova"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.2'
    compile 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.11'
    compile 'javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:2.2.11'//this is causing conflict
}
```

Thank you very much for the help

EDIT

I tried adding the following:

```
configurations.all{
    resolutionStrategy.force 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
}
```

but got another strange error:

**Error:trouble processing "javax/xml/soap/AttachmentPart.class":
Error:Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
Error:when not building a core library.
....**

Answer (score 0):

These codes in the build.gradle app was the culpit.

```
   androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

after removing them gradle compire error solved.
Also check external Libraries..that extra javax.annotation-api-1.2 isnt there anymore.Enjoy!!